# How to fetch data from attendance machine asynchronization with zkemkeeper DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, zkemkeeper

I have one query below,

How to fetch data from attendance machine asynchronization with zkemkeeper dll?

Please if any suggestion or any other idea then let me know.

What I need?
1.I want to connect multiple devices at single time.
2.Once machine connected i want to get data to SQL table.
3.If any user punch after connection then entry will goes to Table directly.

Thanks,

What I have tried:

1.I checked its IP ping first.
2.If getting IP ping then going to establish connection with machine.
3.If machine connected successfully then in transaction table it will mark entry as connected device.
4.After connection its goes for getting all data from machine and check all entry one by one with current table and insert new entry.
5.I set its interval so it will check again after two minutes and again get all data and check all data and insert new entries in table.

I want to make this thing as real time and getting data quickly updated in system.

Note :
-> There will be 40 machines(ESSL)
-> I want to fetch data from this all machines without affecting any process.

Comment: Did you try any thing? what's the issue you are facing? Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: my issue is Fingerprint device does not respond while reading logs from memory for a long time  using SDK.so that the next looping device is not downloading their logs

Comment: https://camsunit.com/application/zk-teco-essl-api-integration.html check if this helps. This link talks about the connecting he biometric devices through push technology

Answer (score 0):

Since, you have 40 devices to be managed. I suggest to go with Push SDK instead of Pull SDK. The documentation is available at https://camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html. In push sdk, you dont need to poll for pulling the data, hence, you will not face the reported issues.
While going with the pull sdk, you may experience of frequent application hanging issues, particularly when the device is offline which you can avoid in push sdk.

and more importantly, all the devices are not required be in a same network where the application is hosted. You can have your application on server and device can communicate over internet (http).